# Where can I buy a spare power cable for a i5 Mac Mini?

Tags: mac-mini, power

I don't see extra power cables for the i5 2011 Mac Mini in the Apple Store Accessory section.

But this power cable looks a lot like black ones I've seen that go between a power brick for a Lenovo laptop and the outlet. Is this the very same cable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided it connects fine you should be ok. It uses a standard power plug with this design. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4806

Otherwise any sort of Apple Service Provider or http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/23-190

Comment: +1 - the cable is a standard connector. The apple cord material is very high quality, but any old [IEC 60320-1 C7 male connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320) will do.

Comment: Yeah, it should be a standard cable.

Answer (score 1):

The Mac Mini uses the standard IEC 60320 C-7 female connector, take a look here for useful reference -

- (ref) http://www.qiao-pu.com/en/IEC-60320-C-7-ac-figure-8-connector-IEC-60320-IEC-C7-female-connector-figure-8-power-cords-99.html
- (pic) http://www.qiao-pu.com/upload/photo/75a07d8e4a1e664433f34a4dc63f83e9.jpg

C-7’s are common and available everywhere (e.g. Amazon, Target, Best Buy, etc.)